# Can we select rows with duplicate entries in Alter Row transformation in Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, expressionbuilder

There are two columns:

| col_A | col_B |
| --- | --- |
| 111 | 2.0 |
| 222 | 1.0 |
| 222 | 2.0 |
| 333 | 1.0 |

Using alter row transformation i would like to select rows that have repeated entries in col_A, in this example 222 and select the corresponding highest value in col_B i.e. 2.0

The output should look as follows:

| col_A | col_B |
| --- | --- |
| 111 | 2.0 |
| 222 | 2.0 |
| 333 | 1.0 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **Aggregate transformation** in Data flow.

This is my source data:

[image]

In the Aggregate transformation, give **col_A for group by** to select the distict rows and **col_B for aggregate**. Use the `max(col_B)` in this to get the max values.

**Group By:**

[image]

**Aggregate:**

[image]

**Result:**

[image]

**Update about Extra Columns:**

To Carry the Remaining columns after aggregation transformation, use Join transformation with Join type as inner join(Join of above with source) and give the above two columns as Keys.

[image]

After Join, you can remove the extra columns with select transformation.

[image]

**Result with Extra rows:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks Rakesh, while i am checking your answer, i want to add something here. For illustration purpose i used one column Col_b. The transformation looks good but there are other extra columns that i need to carry over. Let's say they have a prefix abc present in their name. how can i select all those columns too?

Comment: You want to group by a single columnA and want the max in col_B and also want to carry the remaining columns as well in result?

Comment: Exactly that is what i want.

Comment: 'group by a single columnA and want the max in col_B ', After doing this you can select the remaining column's rows which have max value in col_B.

Comment: do i need to add a column pattern in Aggregate settings in the data flow? or do you know how can i select the remaining columns? they all have "col_" prefix in the names. @RakeshGovindula

Comment: Aggregate requires atleast one aggregate transformation in every column pattern, so to get the extra columns you can follow the above approach I have added.